# Do I need to pre-book shuttles from Haneda Airport to Narita Airport?

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer, tokyo, nrt, hnd

My flight is Jakarta-Haneda, Narita-Canada on the same day. I need to transfer from Haneda to Narita by shuttle bus. Do I have to book the ticket beforehand or could I just pay the ticket fare on the spot?

Comment: Be sure you allow **plenty** of time. There are a lot of steps here (customs, security, etc.) and Tokyo can have horrific traffic.

Comment: @MikeHarris The Narita-Haneda bus actually avoids central Tokyo and is rarely caught in traffic.

Comment: @jpatokal That's good to know. It is still much more complicated than changing planes within the same airport, though.

Answer (score 2):

The bus company has airport terminal floor plans on [their website](https://www.limousinebus.co.jp/en/bus_services/haneda/narita.html) which shows ticket counters, so it must be possible to pay on the spot, though there may be queues:

[image: Narita Terminal 1]

[image: Narita Terminal 2]

Comment: Yes, it's possible to buy tickets on the spot.  In my experience the buses are rarely full, although your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

1. You do not need to book beforehand. Tickets are sold at counter near the exit gate.
2. You can also go by train as a fallback. Train is cheaper, and takes slightly longer.

http://www.haneda-airport.jp/inter/en/access/traffic.html